# Can GNU parallel output stdout before the program has exited?

Tags: gnu-parallel

```
echo 'echo "hello, world!";sleep 3;' | parallel
```

This command does not output anything until it has completed. Parallel's man page claims:

> GNU parallel makes sure output from the commands is the same output as you would get had you run the commands sequentially.

I guess the devil is in the phrasing: you get the same output as if you would run it normally, but not the output the same as if you would run it normally. I've looked for an option that will do this, for example `--results /dev/stdout`, but that does not work.

My use-case is seeing real-time progress output from the command that I'm running. It's not about how many tasks have completed, which parallel could display for me, but about the progress output of each command individually that I want to see.

I would use a bash loop (`for i in $x; do cmd & done;`) but I want to be able to stop all tasks with a single Ctrl+C, which parallel allows me to do.

Is it possible to do this in parallel? If not, is there another tool?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you're looking for `--ungroup`. The man page says:

```
--group  Group output. Output from each jobs is grouped 
         together and is only printed when the command is finished. 

         --group is the default. Can be reversed with -u.
```

`-u` of course is a synonym for `--ungroup`.

Answer (score 15):

To watch progress for a few parallel jobs, try `--tmuxpane --fg`:

```
parallel --tmuxpane --fg seq {} 10000000 ::: {1..100}
```

You could also be looking for `-u` or (more likely) `--lb`.
From `man parallel`:

```
   --line-buffer
   --lb
       Buffer output on line basis. --group will keep the output together
       for a whole job. --ungroup allows output to mixup with half a line
       coming from one job and half a line coming from another job.
       --line-buffer fits between these two: GNU parallel will print a full
       line, but will allow for mixing lines of different jobs.

       --line-buffer takes more CPU power than both --group and --ungroup,
       but can be much faster than --group if the CPU is not the limiting
       factor.

       Normally --line-buffer does not buffer on disk, and can thus process
       an infinite amount of data, but it will buffer on disk when combined
       with: --keep-order, --results, --compress, and --files. This will
       make it as slow as --group and will limit output to the available
       disk space.

       With --keep-order --line-buffer will output lines from the first job
       while it is running, then lines from the second job while that is
       running. It will buffer full lines, but jobs will not mix. Compare:

         parallel -j0 'echo {};sleep {};echo {}' ::: 1 3 2 4
         parallel -j0 --lb 'echo {};sleep {};echo {}' ::: 1 3 2 4
         parallel -j0 -k --lb 'echo {};sleep {};echo {}' ::: 1 3 2 4

       See also: --group --ungroup
```

[...]

```
   --ungroup
   -u  Ungroup output.  Output is printed as soon as possible and by passes
       GNU parallel internal processing. This may cause output from
       different commands to be mixed thus should only be used if you do not
       care about the output. Compare these:

         seq 4 | parallel -j0 \
           'sleep {};echo -n start{};sleep {};echo {}end'
         seq 4 | parallel -u -j0 \
           'sleep {};echo -n start{};sleep {};echo {}end'

       It also disables --tag. GNU parallel outputs faster with -u. Compare
       the speeds of these:

         parallel seq ::: 300000000 >/dev/null
         parallel -u seq ::: 300000000 >/dev/null
         parallel --line-buffer seq ::: 300000000 >/dev/null

       Can be reversed with --group.

       See also: --line-buffer --group
```

One example where `-u` shines is where stdout and stderr is mixed in the same line:

```
echo -n 'This is stdout (';echo -n stderr >&2 ; echo ')'
```

This will be formatted wrongly with `--lb`  and `--group`.

But even `-u` does not guarantee it will be formatted correctly due to the half-line mixing between processes: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Non-atomic_writes_with_xargs_-P

You might also try: --latest-line which reserves a single line on the screen for each job and print the latest line here.

[image: --latest-line]

Comment: I'm getting `parallel: Error: A semaphore does not take input from neither stdin nor a file` for the first command in the answer. GNU parallel 20161222

Comment: @sanmai I cannot reproduce that. Post another question and let us work out what goes wrong for you.

Comment: @sanmai Same here. Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 5):

My solution was to log the output into files and watch it change in real time with `tail -f <file>` command, and then deleting them automatically when the job is done. I also found `--progress` flag useful.

```
parallel --progress ./program {} '>' {}.log';' rm {}.log ::: A B C
```

Here jobs will consist of running `program` with different inputs `A`,`B`,`C` and sending the program's output to the corresponding log files.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution, Andrei!